# Scroll indicator issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to add a vertical scroll indicator to the main page that will fill as you scroll down, however the `globals.css` file conflicts with the scroll indicator and not filling as you scroll down, and only starts to fill on the footer.

In `globals.css` I use the following styles for section and container, which provide a smooth scroll through each screen on the page (`</section>`):

```css
{/*globals.css*/}

{/*...*/}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The problem is solved when I remove `height: 100vh;` in the `.container` class and the scroll indicator works, but it breaks smooth scrolling across screens.

Any thoughts on how this can be resolved?

Here's the [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/full-page-scroll-l3h36m?file=%2Fapp%2Fglobals.css&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00082863g1ez3yql%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8o00032863awf7infs%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00052863gxtpp4zn%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00072863cr91z3vx%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B47.47651990698701%252C52.52348009301299%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cln3cch8o00032863awf7infs%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8o00032863awf7infs%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clohiellt01p52865kojzqrby%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fglobals.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohiellt01p52865kojzqrby%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Ftailwind.config.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohy8ci9003r2866ru5k92c8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fpage.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3ccpnp005a28636mmmn86o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fcomponents%252Fnavbar%252FNavbar.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln4ofngz003n286473tfdddz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fcomponents%252FFooter.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohiaoaw00qt28652p7q5g7y%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fcomponents%252FScrollIndicator.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohyhcth0298286542jrgx6r%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cln3cch8p00072863cr91z3vx%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00072863cr91z3vx%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln4r9o9q008e2864wgaokcxy%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cln4r9o9q008e2864wgaokcxy%2522%257D%252C%2522cln3cch8p00052863gxtpp4zn%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00052863gxtpp4zn%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8o00042863nxyzxagj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8o00042863nxyzxagj%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) demonstrating this.